# convert Date string to array of integers

Tags: java, string, date

I have a string in the format: "YYYY-MM-DD" and I want to convert it into an array of integer

this is my code :

```
int year, month, day;
Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

for example, if the date is 2017-03-16 I want my array be like [2017,3,16].

Comment: Honestly, I'd start with `LocalDate` and just use it's getters to fill the array - or better yet, just keep on using the instance of `LocalDate`

Comment: ```int year, month, day;``` is not an array of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly i would say to use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) from [java-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API and stop using[Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) legacy date class

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
String dateString = currentDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

If you want to convert date string to int array, then split is based on `-`.

```
Integer[] array = 
    Arrays
    .stream( dateString.split("-") )
    .map( Integer::valueOf )
    .toArray( Integer[]::new )
;
```

Comment: In addition to that: **Don't** use the old classes ```Date``` and ```SimpleDateFormat```. Use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) that is much more robust and has a better api design than the old stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense if all of your dates were preformatted as described in your question.  But if you are using date Objects I would take advantage of the Java 8+ capabilities.

First, define a `lambda` to extract the parts and return an array. Note that you can add other date components or easily change the order in the array.

```
        Function<LocalDate, int[]> getParts =
                ld -> new int[] { ld.getDayOfMonth(),
                        ld.getMonthValue(), ld.getYear() };
```

Then you can apply it like so.

```
        LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 15);
        int[] parts = getParts.apply(d);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Prints

```
[15, 3, 2020]
```

Or this

```
        // create a list of LocalDate objects.
        List<LocalDate> localDates = List.of(
        LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 15), LocalDate.of(2020, 3, 16));
        // and convert to a list of arrays of date attributes.
        List<int[]> dates = localDates.stream().map(getParts::apply)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
        dates.forEach(a->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

Prints

```
[15, 3, 2020]
[16, 3, 2020]
```

Another advantage of this is that you don't have to ensure the format is the same from date to date.

Comment: For most purposes this would be my preferrence (though I upvoted the other answer too).

Answer (score 0):

It's very quick and easy. If you are bound to use an array, the solution =>
import these=>

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
```

then in your main or other method =>

```
    int[] dateArray = new int[100]; // or your desired size

    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    String[] line = strDate.split("-");

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
    {
        dateArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i]);
    }
```

should do it.